# How do I add a class to specific html elements, If they contain a certain value

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, select, jquery-selectors

For example, I have the below html:

```
<div id="stuff">
<span>1</span><span>2</span><span>3</span>
</div>
```

And I need to select some in this fashion:

```
$('#stuff').find('<span>1</span><span>2</span>').addClass('2');
```

Which should turn the html into this:

```
   <div id="stuff">
    <span class="2">1</span><span class="2">2</span><span>3</span>
    </div>
```

However, the above does not work. Anyone know how to use jQuery to select things directly off the DOM by looking for the html?

Also, the span's must be selected in order, so if I had this:

```
<div id="stuff">
<span>2</span><span>3</span><span>1</span>
</div>
```

And used the above JS, it would not do anything.

Comment: You need some way to differentiate the spans you want to select.

Comment: So, what's the criteria? We understand what needs to happen, but will you always want to select `1` and `2`?

Comment: Sorry about that, somebody removed the bottom part, which contains some critical info. It's back now

Comment: So you want to match by HTML string?

Comment: Yes, That's exactly what I want

Comment: Where does the string come from?  Do you need to match different patterns or just `<span>1</span>`?

Comment: @kpsuperplane: That still provides no information as to what needs to be matched. Also, to reply to someone, use the @ mention syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$( '#stuff span:not(:contains(3))' ).addClass( '2' )`

Comment: That's just an example. I would have hundred's of spans with all kinds of different things in them.

Comment: I understand that my question is unusual, I've been using jquery for years. However, I can't think of a good way to accomplish this.

Comment: Explain better what you want to .. select all elements that are in an array, and add the class 2?

Comment: Nope, just the ones that I want to select, and the ones I want to select must be in order... Thanks for responding though.

Answer (score 1):

right, if you want to look for various contents, do this:

```
<html>
   <head>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript">
          $(function(){
                 var contains = [ 1 , 2 , 6 , 7 , 8 ] ;
                 $.map ( contains, function ( i ) {
                        $ ( '#stuff span:contains("'+ i +'")' ).addClass ( '2' ) ;
                 } ) ;
          });
          </script>
   </head>
   <body>
          <div id="stuff">
                 <span>1</span>
                 <span>2</span>
                 <span>3</span>
                 <span>4</span>
                 <span>5</span>
                 <span>6</span>
                 <span>7</span>
                 <span>8</span>
          </div>
   </body>
```

The output:

```
<div id="stuff">
       <span class="2">1</span>
       <span class="2">2</span>
       <span>3</span>
       <span>4</span>
       <span>5</span>
       <span class="2">6</span>
       <span class="2">7</span>
       <span class="2">8</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `:contains` pseudo-class:

```
$('#stuff span:contains(1), #stuff span:contains(2)').addClass('2');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SJxTu/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally clear on what your selection condition is, but you Could use the jquery filter method with a function to select the spans.

For example from the docs:

```
$('li').filter(function(index) {
   return $('strong', this).length == 1;
}).css('background-color', 'red');
```

http://api.jquery.com/filter/

You would need to check if $(this).text() === whatever